getting this error in Sql Reportng Services 2019 : Error while loading code module: RtfToHTML, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’
Error while loading code module: RtfToHTML, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'RtfToHTML, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
tried to move around the RTFToHtml.dll in the server

Seems that the dll file is missing from your report server BIN directory.
